# Linux can't read an integer encoded by BitConverter.GetBytes()

Tags: c#, c, sockets

I made a client in C#, and I would like to have a server build under Linux, in C.

I use a prefix with "message" length for every "message".
I encode it to `byte[]` array by using `BitConverter.GetBytes()` (4 bytes array).
After that I send it by

```
socket.Send(prefix, prefix.Length, 0);
```

The C server on Linux can't read the number. It displays a strange character, despite it read 4 bytes.

Linux side looks like

```
char prefix[4];
int bytes = 0;
bytes = recv(s, prefix, 4, 0);
printf("%s", prefix);
```

If I encode the number by using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`, Linux understands it correctly.

I tested it, and it looks the problem is only when the programs are coded in these 2 different languages.

What's going on?

Comment: Please show the receiving code.

Comment: Why are you printing it as a *string*? It's a 4-byte encoded integer - it's not text. You should be converting it *back* to a 32-bit integer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I try `int n = (int) prefix;` and the result is 'Segmentation fault'.

Comment: Well I didn't say to try to just cast a pointer... how much C experience do you have, and do you understand what the *values* within `prefix` will mean? (If your variant of C has a better byte representation than char, you should use that by the way.)

Comment: In this moment I try to solve the issue basing on the first answer for my question here. I don't understand that solution you mean.

Comment: You didn't answer either of my questions... don't just try random bits of code... make sure you understand what's happening, why it doesn't currently work, and *then* how to fix it.

Comment: OK. The prefix value is in the binary representation. So, I must convert it to the decimal representation to get the integer, right?

Comment: Not really. You've just got to take those values and probably use bitshifting to get them into an appropriate value, depending on the endianness of BitConverter on your C# system, and your Linux system. Start off by thinking what the values in `prefix` will be for a length of 258, for example...

Comment: It looks a bit complicated for me. Maybe there is some other kind of encoding these prefixes.

Comment: It's not desperately complicated, but you *do* need to think about it rather than just expecting a one line solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `BitConverter.GetBytes()` will give you a **binary** representation - something that is not a printable character in most cases (try the int 0x20202020, this should give you one or more spaces), but perfect for processing purpouses. You can print it with something like `printf("%d",the_int_variable)`
- `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` will give you s **string** representation - something, that is nice for printing it to the console, but suboptimal for processing.

**Edit**

After your updated question, change `printf("%s", prefix);` to `printf("%d", prefix);` after changing prefix to type int and retry.

Comment: `prefix` must be made of type `int` to use `printf("%d", prefix);`. And beware of endianess ...

Comment: @EugenRieck how to do that? I try `int n = (int) prefix;` and the result is 'Segmentation fault'.

Comment: Something like `int prefix;` instead of `char prefix[4];`, then `bytes = recv(s, &prefix, 4, 0);`, then `printf("%s", prefix);` - I am not a C guru.